# Selenium and Chromedriver and Python running from Cron

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, raspberry-pi5

I have been running `Selenium`, `Chromedriver` and Python on a Raspberry Pi 5. Because `Chromedriver` does not really have a version for ARM for download but there is a version on APT according

[https://forums.raspberrypi.com/viewtopic.php?p=2155925#p2155925](https://#https://forums.raspberrypi.com/viewtopic.php?p=2155925#p2155925)

So, I have been using this and it all works well when I am running via Geany

So, I have finished and now want to run this python script via CRON, so I put the details in but I am getting errors.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   File "/home/dean/main_venv/luxpowerdl.py", line 69, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   File "/home/dean/main_venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py", line 45, in __init__
    super().__init__(   File "/home/dean/main_venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chromium/webdriver.py", line 61, in __init__
    super().__init__(command_executor=executor, options=options)   File "/home/dean/main_venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 208, in __init__
    self.start_session(capabilities)   File "/home/dean/main_venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 292, in start_session
    response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, caps)["value"]
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   File "/home/dean/main_venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 347, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)   File "/home/dean/main_venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 229, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace) selenium.common.exceptions.SessionNotCreatedException: Message: session not created: Chrome failed to start: exited normally.   (session not created: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)   (The process started from chrome location /usr/bin/chromium-browser is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.) Stacktrace:
#0 0x5555f50dc3e4 <unknown>
#1 0x5555f4e11ac8 <unknown>
#2 0x5555f4e40fac <unknown>
#3 0x5555f4e3dc44 <unknown>
#4 0x5555f4e7cf08 <unknown>
#5 0x5555f4e48d74 <unknown>
#6 0x5555f4e49760 <unknown>
#7 0x5555f50a6a74 <unknown>
#8 0x5555f50a9e04 <unknown>
#9 0x5555f5096d7c <unknown>
#10 0x5555f50aa714 <unknown>
#11 0x5555f507f0e0 <unknown>
#12 0x5555f50cbbc4 <unknown>
#13 0x5555f50cbdc0 <unknown>
#14 0x5555f50db5b4 <unknown>
#15 0x7fff46fcee58 <unknown>
#16 0x7fff47037f9c <unknown>
```

The local where APT installs `Chromedriver` is usr/bin, it has Root as owner and permissions are good.

usr/bin is in my $PATH.

So, the python files runs fine from Geany, my user terminal, my user name is in the Root group, Chromedriver has root as owner with permissions for root as rwx, group as r-x and others as r-x and is also marked as an executable.

Any ideas how I can get `cron` (using `crontab -e`) to has access to `chromedriver`.

PS, Chromium browser is installed. All using Raspberry Pi 5 running Debian Bookworm.

Answer (score 0):

Finally found a reference to having to use `DISPLAY=:0` in my cron entry, I did not think even this would work as it requires X to be running but Debian Bookworm is using Wayland, anyway I gave it a go and it ran perfectly.

So my cron entry is now:

```
*/15 * * * * DISPLAY=:0 /home/dean/main_venv/bin/python main_venv/luxpowerdl.py > main/venv/logs/luxpowerdl.log 2>&1
```